# How do I center my banner and make it at the top?

Tags: css

So here is my CSS code.

```
    IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:0px;
                    }
```

And it is centred but not at the top?
I have searched around the internet to no prevail any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks for reading.

Comment: FYI: top,left,right and bottom css rules works only with [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) elements!

Comment: Please create a fiddle or provide us with a link to your site.

Answer (score 0):

When using `top:0px;` you must give it a position of `position:fixed;` or `position:absolute;`.
As in:

```
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
 }
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/7M47e/)

Comment: you may also need to assign a `position:relative;` to the appropriate parent

Comment: How do I know what is the appropiate parent? (Sorry I am a newbie :P )

Comment: When it is inside another element tag, that is its parent. As in: <div id="parent"><div id="child">I am a child!</div></div> Id parent is the parent of id child.

Comment: you want to assign `position:relative;` to the parent element that you want the child to be positioned against. This could be the body, or maybe a div inside the body. Since you are talking about the header banner, the body will probably do the trick.

Comment: I put "position:relative;" inside my div (in no particular place) and it printed it out onto the screen like normal text? (Mind posting the exact css and html code that I need?)

Comment: @user3674383 Place it in the parents CSS or else inline like so:<div id="parent" style="position:relative"><div id="child">I am a child!</div></div>

Comment: This is my result? http://totallytruenews.com/test.html ,Would it be possible if  you could just post the exact code I need so I could study it?

Comment: Sure, this is my html <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Test </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">



</HEAD>

<body>

div id="image" style="position:relative">
<img src = "truth.png" />

</div>







</body>


</HTML>

Comment: And here is my css,            IMG.image{
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
 }

Comment: Why do you have the css for a nav tag if you have no nav tag?

Comment: Thats for something else on the current main site.

Comment: @user3674383 I applied the nav class anyway but [here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/j9URj/2/show/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you mean the banner is not flush against the top of the screen.  Add `body { margin:0px; }` and that should fix your issue.

Comment: You add it anywhere in your CSS file

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
IMG.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
 }
 </style>
```